# RedHat 5.4 Monitor File For Changes

Tags: linux, redhat

How can I monitor when a file is changed, and specifically who changed it (or perhaps what cron job changed it) on a RedHat machine without installing additional software?

I am a system admin for the machine, but for reasons I wont go into here, I cannot install software on the box.

Is there any built in functionality or a python or bash script I can run? I've found many options for file monitoring software, but I can't install anything on the server.

Comment: `watch` may be what you are looking for; have a look at the man page. It's part of a regular unix system.

Answer (score 1):

So, I'm assuming that you don't want to installing anything to this antique, but have root access?

[Here is a similar question on a different stack exchange site that may well work.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92013/monitoring-file-changes-process-access-to-files)

Comment: Yes that is correct. I do have root access to the box, but do not want to (nor can I) install anything to the box.

Comment: I took a look at the other questions. Each of the answers doesnt quite fit...

First answer: Install software. Doenst fit. Second Answer: Watch might work. I will try this, but I dont think I can get the user who changed the file. Third answer: strace requires I know the PID of the process editing the file, which I dont. Fourth answer: lsof may work for me. I'll need to create a bash script that gets this info every 1/10th of a second, because thats how long the script thats editing the file seems to run for.

Answer (score 1):

You need auditing of some sort. Since you have RHEL, you have selinux. If it's set to Permissive mode and have a rule in place to do so, it'll log when someone writes to it (or at least when they open it read/write).